# How paypal accept payment without amount field

Tags: paypal

```
                <input style="WIDTH: 10px"

                      value="_s-xclick"

                      type="hidden"

                      name="cmd"> <input style="WIDTH: 10px"

                      value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

                      type="hidden"

                      name="hosted_button_id"> <input border="0"

                      alt="PayPal &mdash; The safer, easier way to pay online."

                      src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/SG/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"

                      type="image"

                      name="submit"> <img style="WIDTH: 1px; HEIGHT: 1px"

                      border="0"

                      alt=""

                      src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif">

            </form>
```

How this work while there is no item name field , nor amount but when I click it redirect me to paypal site , without any error , I fount price and item name well ,any Idea how it works?

Comment: Where is the rest of the form code?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

When you used hosted buttons created through your account all of the variables and values are saved within your account. The "hosted_button_id" value is unique to your account; it pulls out all the values you entered when creating the button.

If you created an unhosted / unencrypted button you would have the full HTML code.